# Panel not hiding when clicked second time - Expansion Panel and Collapsable panel Implementation in angular mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing the Expansion panel and collapsable panel. Here is my code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ygdrrokyvkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html).

```html
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = element">
</tr>
```

It is working except, when I click for first time, the expansion panel is opening and **when I click second time, it should get collapsed**, but it's not happening.

I found [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows) (see "Table with expandable rows" section) in official docs which works. [A working example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxlvynvpxnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts). Why is collapsible panel not working when clicked second time in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
(click)="expandedElement = element">
```

#### Solution:

You should set `expandedElement` to `null` when you click on the **same** element:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
  // ...
  (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
</tr>
```